# Cannot dynamically link to components in a custom bpl

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder, bpl, borland-c++

While drafting the following post I found a solution, but I thought it might be still worthwhile to post here for reference. See solution below.

---

In RAD studio (C++), I have a project group with multiple dlls and exes that rely on a standard set of custom controls. I have isolated these controls in a borland package (bpl) so that I can use them in Design view.

Now whenever I drag one of my custom controls from the component palette to a form, it seems the component is actually statically linked into the project containing the form. This is not what I want, and it leads to problems since some of my controls rely on additional resources linked into the bpl.

I already removed the #pragma link line that RAD Studio adds automatically, but the component is still linked into the executable. I cannot see how this happens.

Any ideas?

---

OK, the solution is rather easy: In project options, go to page "Packages" and under "Build with runtime packages", enter the name of the package (without the bpl extension) that contains the common components. Done.

Comment: Stack overflow encourages you to post an answer if you've found it yourself. Don't put "solved" there, write an answer. You are even encouraged to accept your own answer if it the one that fits your problem best. Btw, welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Hendrik:

"OK, the solution is rather easy: In project options, go to page "Packages" and under "Build with runtime packages", enter the name of the package (without the bpl extension) that contains the common components. Done."